# Hi ! Is there any possibility in which i can display gallery images in React-Native View. If select any image and change profile picture?

Tags: react-native

I am already using the 'React-native-image-picker' but I want to display gallery images in a View. If I select the image It will change the profile image ??

Answer (score 0):

Check this library: https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll#getphotos

You can get the images in the albums, and render them into your View, using `CameraRoll.getPhotos(params);`

Example

```
_handleButtonPress = () => {
   CameraRoll.getPhotos({
       first: 20,
       assetType: 'Photos',
     })
     .then(r => {
       this.setState({ photos: r.edges });
     })
     .catch((err) => {
        //Error Loading Images
     });
   };
render() {
 return (
   <View>
     <Button title="Load Images" onPress={this._handleButtonPress} />
     <ScrollView>
       {this.state.photos.map((p, i) => {
       return (
         <Image
           key={i}
           style={{
             width: 300,
             height: 100,
           }}
           source={{ uri: p.node.image.uri }}
         />
       );
     })}
     </ScrollView>
   </View>
 );
}
```